# PHP 2 way communicating asynchronous socket server

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous, signals

Good afternoon Gurus,

I'd like to write an asynchronous 2 way communication socket server in PHP.
If a client connects to server, it's forks a child process and parent waits for another client to connect.
The child process uses socket_read() function for incoming data.
If there is any data to send back to the client another process sends USR1 signal to the socket process, which reads data from shared memory / database and uses socket_write() function to send data back to client while there can be new incoming data so socket_read must be in loop.

The problem is that USR1 signal handler function is blocked by socket_read and the outgoing data is only send when the connected client sends anything through the socket.
I have to send data to client ASAP

I was thinking of 3 solutions:

- When a client connects the parent process creates 2 child processes
  one for reading and another one for sending data. Am I able to share
  socket source between 2 processes?
- Instead of USR1 signal I would send dummy data through the same socket which sends the data back to client
- Somehow brake the socket_read to receive the signal

I've tried socket_recv function with MSG_DONTWAIT flag which returns immediately so I was able to handle signal but I think it's resource-intensive, isn't it?

```
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sigUsr");
while(true) {
    // blocks pcntl_signal function call
    if (($data = @socket_read($this->connection,$len,PHP_BINARY_READ)) === false) { 
        break;
    } else {
    // handle incoming $data
    }
}

function sigUsr(){
    echo "SIGUSR1\n";
    // read $data from DB
    return socket_write($this->connection, $data, strlen($data));
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Adam